# Utility to convert document in Evernote Markup Language (ENML) to MSWord?

Tags: html, ms-word, evernote

I would like to convert documents which are in Evernote Markup Language (ENML) to HTML/DOCX/ODT.

I'm looking for a utility / example code or maybe pointer where to start. There is probably some open source project which have infrastructure for conversions like one I want.

Answer (score 0):

To edit enml documents http://enml-editor.ping13.net/ to convert Evernote notes to html use the ~export function to save as html.